# Telerik reporting in ASP.NET MVC 4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, telerik-reporting

I try to implement Telerik Report in my WebApp and get runtime error.

> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException:
>   GenericArguments[0],'BuilkReport.Areas.Report.Template.PoReport', on
>   'Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.Current.ReportSerializable`1[TReport]'
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'TReport'.

These are the methods I use:

1. Create a telerik report and create parameters for its constructor
2. Create a model using Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource as one of data members
3. Use controller to get proper parameter for the model, then pass it to the view

These steps worked fine, with data going correctly as planned. In the view part, I use method found in this demo : http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/reporting/general/using-telerik-web-reportviewer-in-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx

I simply copy those views into my project and pass the model from controller to be passed to `ReportViewer1.ReportSource` (instead of creating a new one like in the demo project)

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is released a preview of the beta HTML5 Report Viewer - [Bringing the Power of HTML5 to Telerik Reporting](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/13-09-23/bringing-the-power-of-html5-to-telerik-reporting)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the steps outlined here -
http://blogs.telerik.com/careypayette/posts/13-03-26/telerik-reporting-in-mvc-sure-it-takes-8-quick-steps-